# How to comment out knockout code in HTML

Tags: html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Is there any to comment out a knock out code in HTML, since the ko code is already in default html comment block.

```
<!-- ko if : isEditable() -->
    <!-- Edit Mode -->
    <div class="edit">Edit mode</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Can I comment the above section in my html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the ko to anything else!

`<!-- koc if : isEditable() --> or <!-- kcomment if : isEditable() -->` anything other that ko makes it as a comment.

As knockout looks only for html comments that start with ko,  anything other than ko on an html comment will simply be a comment.

Answer (score 7):

In our project we tend to use `<!-- kocomment if : isEditable() --><!-- /kocomment -->` syntax which effectively turns `ko statement` into a simple html comment (knockout does not care for such comments).

Or you may use shorter additions to `ko` word. Just make sure to comment out both opening and closing statement, there is also risk that this commented comment will not stand out, unless you have some knockout syntax highlighting.